# SD card image creation for RPi with U-Boot and redundant U-Boot environment in MMC

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, sd-card, u-boot

I'm fairly new to embedded linux and I'm currently working on a device using a Raspberry Pi 3B+. The OS is built using Buildroot and the device can be upgraded with a double-copy strategy using `swupdate` and U-Boot (v2019.01) but at the moment the upgrade process hasn't been completely power-safe since the u-boot environment is not redundant and it's stored as a single file in the rpi boot FAT partition.

To make things safer i'm trying to store the u-boot environment redundantly  directly in the mmc memory (the SD card) in two different partitions. To create the SD card image i use `genimage` and the cfg file is as follows:

```
image boot.vfat {
  vfat {
    files = {
      "bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb",
      "bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb",
      "bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb",
      "rpi-firmware/bootcode.bin",
      "rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt",
      "rpi-firmware/config.txt",
      "rpi-firmware/fixup.dat",
      "rpi-firmware/start.elf",
      "rpi-firmware/overlays",
      "zImage",
      "u-boot.bin",
    }
  }
  size = 16777216
}


image user-data.ext4 {
  ext4 {
  }

  size = 64M
  mountpoint = "user-data"
}


image sdcard.img {
  hdimage {
  }

  partition boot {
    partition-type = 0xC
    bootable = "true"
    image = "boot.vfat"
  }

  partition UbootEnvA {
    partition-type = 0xA3
    image = "uboot-env.bin"
    size = 16384
  }

  partition UbootEnvB {
    partition-type = 0xA3
    image = "uboot-env.bin"
    size = 16384
  }

  partition rootfsA {
    partition-type = 0x83
    image = "rootfs.ext4"
  }

  partition rootfsB {
    partition-type = 0x83
    image = "rootfs.ext4"
  }

  partition film-dev-data {
    partition-type = 0x83
    image = "user-data.ext4"
  }
}
```

Partitions `UbootEnvA` and `UbootEnvB` are use the environment image created using `mkenvimage`.

When the device boots I get the usual `Loading Environment from MMC... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment` message and if I use the `mmc part` command in the uboot shell I get the following list:

```
Partition Map for MMC device 0  --   Partition Type: DOS

Part    Start Sector    Num Sectors UUID        Type
  1 1           32768       00000000-01 0c Boot
  2 32769       32          00000000-02 a3
  3 32801       32          00000000-03 a3
  4 32833       950275      00000000-04 0f Extd
  5 32834       409600      00000000-05 83
  6 442435      409600      00000000-06 83
  7 852036      131072      00000000-07 83
```

Partitions 2 and 3 are the ones corresponding to `UbootEnvA` and `UbootEnvB` and sectors are 512 bytes long so i thought the offsets for the environment to be used in the U-Boot source code could be calculated as:

```
32769 * 512 = 16777728 (for the primary one)
32801 * 512 = 16794112 (for the redundant one)
```

So I added the following defines to U-boot source code by patching `uboot-2019.01/include/configs/rpi.h` and then recompiled:

```
#define CONFIG_SYS_MMC_ENV_DEV 0
#define CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET 16777728
#define CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET_REDUND 16794112
```

But after this i still get the same 'Bad CRC' error when U-Boot tries to load the environment.

I'm clearly missing something here since i'm no embedded linux guru. I'm not sure if it's in the `genimage` cfg file, in the U-Boot environment offsets or in the way I computed the offsets.

I really wish i could use a redundant environment int the FAT boot  partition but after looking at the `uboot-2019.01/env/fat.c` file it seems that there's no support for such a thing.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looking at U-boot FAT management source code seems that redundant environment mechanism is missing.